# Reallocating array within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am writing a program for school that is asking us to create a struct which has an integer array as well as two integer variables, capacity and size, that keep track of, you guessed it, the array's size and capacity.  The trouble is starting when I need to reallocate space for the array (the professor doesn't want us using `realloc`).  Here is the code...

#### dynamicArray.h file

```
#ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INCLUDED
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INCLUDED 1

#ifndef __TYPE
#define __TYPE
# define TYPE int
# endif

typedef struct DynArr DynArr;

/* Dynamic Array Functions */
void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity);
DynArr *newDynArr(int cap);

void freeDynArr(DynArr *v);
void deleteDynArr(DynArr *v);

int sizeDynArr(DynArr *v);

void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val);    

#endif
```

#### dynamicArray.c file

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dynArray.h"

struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};

void printArray(DynArr *v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", v->data[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
    /* checking that v has been initialized*/
    assert(v != 0);

    /*check if capacity is reached and increase if necessary*/
    if(v->size >= v->capacity)
    {
        _dynArrSetCapacity(v, (v->capacity) * 2);
    }

    /*add new value to array*/
    v->data[v->size] = val;

    /*increment size of array*/
    v->size++;

}

void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr *v, int newCap)
{
    /*check that v is initialized*/
    assert(v!=0);

    /*create temporary array with new capacity*/
    DynArr *tmp = newDynArr(newCap);

    /*copy contents of v to new array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        tmp->data[i] = v->data[i];
        tmp->size++;
    }

    /*delete contents of old array*/
    deleteDynArr(v);

    /*assign address of new array to v*/
    v = tmp;
}

void deleteDynArr(DynArr *v)
{
    freeDynArr(v);
    free(v);
}

void freeDynArr(DynArr *v)
{
    if(v->data != 0)
    {
        free(v->data);  /* free the space on the heap */
        v->data = 0;    /* make it point to null */
    }
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = 0;
}

DynArr *newDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    DynArr *r = (DynArr *)malloc(sizeof( DynArr));
    assert(r != 0);
    initDynArr(r,cap);
    return r;
}

void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v!= 0);
    v->data = (TYPE *) malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}
```

#### main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dynArray.h"

#define TYPE int

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    DynArr *dyn;
    dyn = newDynArr(2);

    printf("\n\nTesting addDynArr...\n");
    addDynArr(dyn, 3);
    printArray(dyn);
    addDynArr(dyn, 4);
    printArray(dyn);
    addDynArr(dyn, 10);
    printArray(dyn);
    addDynArr(dyn, 5);
    printArray(dyn);
    addDynArr(dyn, 6);
    printArray(dyn);

    return 0;
}
```

I cut the code down (I know if probably doesn't look like it) so this is the essentials of my problem.  I am getting a segmentation fault in the `dynamicArray.c` file.  Specifically in this function

```
void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
    /* checking that v has been initialized*/
    assert(v != 0);

    /*check if capacity is reached and increase if necessary*/
    if(v->size >= v->capacity)
    {
        _dynArrSetCapacity(v, (v->capacity) * 2);
    }

    /*add new value to array*/
    v->data[v->size] = val;

    /*increment size of array*/
    v->size++;

}
```

at the v->data[v->size] = val; line.  I did notice that when I check what the value of v->size is right before the previously mentioned line of code it is giving me garbage values back.  This makes me think that when I pass v into the `_dynArrSetCapacity` function it is being passed by value instead of by reference but I am not seeing how that is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `v = tmp;` in `_dynArrSetCapacity` does not change the caller's passed-in `v`. You're changing a local variable. Suggest you utilize that otherwise unused function return value to return `tmp` from the function and assign it to `v` back in the caller.

Comment: Note that names starting with underscore are basically reserved for use by the implementation (the compiler and library).  The full story is more nuanced, but not by a large margin.  Your `_dynArrSetCapacity` function appears to be unused outside the source file — it should be `static` and should really not start with an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr *v, int newCap)`. You may want to check all of your functions that involve memory reallocation for similar problems.

Technically, there are no references in C, so every parameter is passed by value, or copied. But what you copied was the pointer, not the whole `DynArray` object. Meaning when you did `deleteDynArray()`, the memory disappears like you'd expect, but when you get to `v = tmp;`, it changes the value of the local `v` (local copy) instead of the `v` that was passed in. Then when you get back to `v->data[v->size] = val;`, you're potentially accessing memory that hasn't been assigned, giving you that error.

The quickest fix (IMO not the best though) would be to use a double pointer instead of a single pointer for any of the functions that does deallocation like so:

```
void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr **v, int newCap)
{
    DynArr *tmp = newDynArr(newCap);

    /*copy contents of v to new array*/
    ......
    /*delete contents of old array*/
    deleteDynArr(*v);

    /*assign address of new array to v*/
    *v = tmp;
    (*v)->size = newCap;
}
```

There is an alternative, and I think that might be better. You don't have to reallocate the whole object. Just the block of memory in the `DynArray` object holding all the relevant objects: `TYPE *data`

```
void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr *v, int newCap)
{
    TYPE *tmp = (TYPE*)malloc(sizeof(Type) * newCap);

    /*copy contents of v to new array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; ++i)
        tmp[i] = v->data[i];
    /*delete contents of old array*/
    free(v->data);

    /*assign address of new array to v*/
    v->data = tmp;
    v->size = newCap;
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I walk away from my computer for a bit and come back to find a ton of great answers and information.  Thanks for all the responses. Alex Yan your second suggestion for allocation of the array instead of the whole struct works great and @JonathanLeffler put the finishing touch on it.  Thanks!